# opengl pass texture to program: once or at every rendering?

Tags: opengl, textures

I've a program with two texture: one from a video, and one from an image.

For the image texture, do I have to pass it to the program at each rendering, or can I do it just once? ie can I do

```
glActiveTexture(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE1))
glBindTexture(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), texture.id)
glUniform1i(textureLocation, 1)
```

just once? I believed so, but in my experiment, this works ok if there no video texture involved, but as soon as I add the video texture that I'm attaching at every rendering pass (since it's changing) the only way to get the image is to run the above code at each rendering frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's dissect what your doing, including some unnecessary stuff, and what the GL does.

First of all, none of the C-style casts you're doing in your code are necessary. Just use `GL_TEXTURE_2D` and so on instead of `GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D)`.

`glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + i)`, where `i` is in the range `[0, GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS - 1]`, selects the currently active *texture unit*. Commands that alter texture unit state will affect unit `i` as long as you don't call `glActiveTexture` with another valid unit identifier.

As soon as you call `glBindTexture(target, name)` with the current active texture unit `i`, the state of the texture unit is changed to refer to `name` for the specified `target` when sampling it with the appropriate sampler in a shader (i.e. `name` might be bound to `TEXTURE_2D` and the corresponding sample would have to be a `sampler2D`).  You can only bind one texture object to a specific target for the currently active texture unit - so, if you need to sample two 2D textures in your shader, you'd need to use two texture units.

From the above, it should be obvious what `glUniform1i(samplerLocation, i)` does.

So, if you have two 2D textures you need to sample in a shader, you need two texture units and two samplers, each referring to one specific unit:

```
GLuint regularTextureName = 0;
GLunit videoTextureName = 0;

GLint regularTextureSamplerLocation = ...;
GLint videoTextureSamplerLocation = ...;

GLenum regularTextureUnit = 0;
GLenum videoTextureUnit = 1;

// setup texture objects and shaders ...

// make successfully linked shader program current and query
// locations, or better yet, assign locations explicitly in
// the shader (see below) ...

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + regularTextureUnit);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, regularTextureName);
glUniform(regularTextureSamplerLocation, regularTextureUnit);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + videoTextureUnit);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, videoTextureName);
glUniform(videoTextureSampleLocation, videoTextureUnit);
```

Your fragment shader, where I assume you'll be doing the sampling, would have to have the corresponding samplers:

```
layout(binding = 0) uniform sampler2D regularTextureSampler;
layout(binding = 1) uniform sampler2D videoTextureSampler;
```

And that's it. If both texture objects bound to the above units are setup correctly, it doesn't matter if the contents of the texture changes dynamically before each fragment shader invocation - there are numerous scenarios where this is common place, e.g. deferred rendering or any other render-to-texture algorithm so you're not exactly breaking new ground with some video texture.

As to the question on how often you need to do this: you need to do it when you need to do it - don't change state that doesn't need changing. If you never change the bindings of the corresponding texture unit, you don't need to rebind the texture at all. Set them up once correctly and leave them alone.

The same goes for the sampler bindings: if you don't sample other texture objects with your shader, you don't need to change the shader program state at all. Set it up once and leave it alone.

In short: don't change state if don't have to.

**EDIT**: I'm not quite sure if this is the case or not, but if you're using teh same shader with one sampler for *both* textures in separate shader invocations, you'd have to change something, but guess what, it's as simple as letting the sampler refer to another texture unit:

```
// same texture unit setup as before
// shader program is current 

while (rendering)
{
  glUniform(samplerLocation, regularTextureUnit);
  // draw call sampling the regular texture 

  glUniform(samplerLocation, videoTextureUnit);
  // draw call sampling teh video texture
}
```

Comment: (I need the C-style casts because I'm writing Swift and the compiler complains if I don't do that) I know it's stupid..

Comment: @Guig: Actually my bad for assuming you're writing C or C++ code there. As long as you're not using Objective-C ... ;)

Comment: I guess everybody learns and teaches GL differently. I still think it is very important to understand that active texture and binding are global gl state but uniform (location) binding is per program.

Comment: @starmole: What's important is that there is *context state* and *object state* (aside from the distinction between server and client state) and the currently active texture unit is context state. The texture bindings are explicitly *texture unit state*, which makes them sort of a hybrid - they are context state, but you don't change a global `TEXTURE_BINDING_*`, you change the one belonging to the active texture unit. It's basically the same effect as changing object state using a bind-to-modify approach.

Answer (score 3):

You should bind the texture before every draw. You only need to set the location once. You can also do layout(binding = 1) in your shader code for that. The location uniform stays with the program. The texture binding is a global GL state. Also be careful about ActiveTexture: it is a global GL state.

Good practice would be:

- On program creation, once, set texture location (uniform)
- On draw: SetActive(i), Bind(i), Draw, SetActive(i) Bind(0), SetActive(0)

Then optimize later for redundant calls.

Comment: Your explanation contradicts with itself.You don't need to bind the texture before each draw call,because that's a global state.You DO HAVE to submit uniform location per program,at least once, that needs to sample from that texture.

Comment: @MichaelIvanov: How would you explain it better? I was going with the reasonable assumption that there are more than one draw, each with different textures. I don't see a contradiction? I tried to point out that location is per program, and binding global. And the easiest (not most efficient) way to deal with global state is to just set it.

Comment: Yeah,right, now it seem more reasonable to me; ) You say,"if we need to bind different texture on each draw call we rebind, but the locations can be set just once per program ",correct?